# Taking the filename alone... in PHP

Tags: php

I am able to upload a zip file and compress it, now i need the filename alone... but when i try to reach the name i get along with zip.

asas.text = "upload/" +fileRef.name + "/" +as.text;

Also How can i point the current viewing URL before the upload path.. something if

http://www.yahoo.com/upload/filename/ If the file is viewed from yahoo domain

Comment: Please edit your question for clarity. Your sentences are disjointed and hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [basename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function.

```
$fileName = basename('/path/to/file.zip'); // $fileName == 'file.zip';
```

I **think** you're asking for the server name? Using your example above:

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; // prints "www.yahoo.com"
```